# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') when trying to normalize data

Tags: python

Why I'm I getting this error when I have dropped all the NaN's an the data is in percent? Can't figure this out since the data should not be to large or have any infinity values either.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np

df['Close_mid'] = [752.69, 736.09, 746.39, 749.97, 761.68, 762.08, 768.05, 782.25, 784.65, 786.72, 770.59]

def remove_nan(DataFrame):
    return DataFrame.dropna(inplace=True) 

df['returns'] = 100 * df['Close_mid'].pct_change()
remove_nan(df)
x_array = np.array(df['returns'])
x_array= x_array.reshape(-1, 1)
normalized_X = preprocessing.normalize(x_array)

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
----> 5 normalized_X = preprocessing.normalize(x_array)
```

Comment: We could answer your question much better if you show us data that causes that error, as in [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RoryDaulton You are right, added a small set of the return data

Comment: What are `preprocessing.normalize`, `df['Close_mid']`? Can you provide a _complete_ example?

Comment: @N.Wouda Sure, added a sample from df['Close_mid'] and the dependencies

Comment: @MisterButter thank you for your quick response. When I run this code, I get a `ValueError` as the number of values do not agree. If I remove a value such that the lengths agree, I cannot reproduce your error. Can you provide a _minimal_, but _complete_ (i.e., it runs as-is and shows your problem) example? You're quite close already!

Comment: What happes is that I create df['returns'] = 100 * df['Close_mid'].pct_change(), this puts a nan value in the first row of 'returns' since the first value of 'Close_mid' doesn't have any percentage change. That's why I have the remove_nan function run afterwards

Comment: Hmm, thank you for the input on how I can make the question clearer. But I've tried running my small sample and couldn't neither reproduce my error. I believe something must be wrong in df[returns], but when I run df['returns].isnull().sum() I get 0.

Comment: @MisterButter can you test if any value in `df['Close_mid']` is zero (or close to it)? If so, the percentage change period-to-period might result in a division by zero somewhere down the line, and thus an `infinity` value. That'd be my best guess as to what's wrong here.

Comment: @N.Wouda I checked and the values are between 200-800

Comment: @N.Wouda Please see https://github.com/timoudas/GARCH-LSTM for full code and all the data if you still find yourself having the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use the data files you linked to, and describe the data set, I find,

```
>>>print(df.describe())
       Close_large    Close_mid  Close_small
count  3077.000000  3077.000000  3077.000000
mean    121.647894   432.353685   425.614839
std      30.558998   204.394909   201.607000
min      53.410000     0.000000     0.000000
25%      98.800000   273.090000   278.740000
50%     117.040000   330.580000   339.260000
75%     147.690000   598.490000   547.570000
max     179.370000   870.110000   929.140000
```

Of special interest is of course the `min` row, which suggest you do indeed have a division-by-zero issue when computing the percentage changes. The offending record is the following,

```
>>>print(df[df['Close_mid'] == 0])
            Close_large  Close_mid  Close_small
Date                                           
2008-06-06        96.76        0.0          0.0
```

But you should probably first ensure your date columns line up nicely (this date itself does not exist in this form in the data, and the date columns are also not all named the same).

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your precious time to help, highly appreciate it! Will look into this